# App crashes as soon as it starts?

Tags: java, android

```
01-19 17:59:15.238: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8182):     getCSCPackageItemText()
01-19 17:59:15.238: I/PersonaManager(8182): getPersonaService() name     persona_policy
01-19 17:59:15.288: I/dalvikvm(8182): Could not find method     android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
01-19 17:59:15.288: W/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     11426: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted     (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
01-19 17:59:15.288: D/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-19 17:59:15.288: I/dalvikvm(8182): Could not find method     android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
01-19 17:59:15.288: W/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     11432: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
01-19 17:59:15.288: D/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-19 17:59:15.288: I/dalvikvm(8182): Could not find method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,     referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScroll    Enabled
01-19 17:59:15.288: W/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     9005:     Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
01-19 17:59:15.288: D/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
01-19 17:59:15.298: D/dalvikvm(8182): DexOpt: couldn't find static field     Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;.Toolbar_buttonGravity
01-19 17:59:15.298: W/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: unable to resolve static field     3142 (Toolbar_buttonGravity) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
01-19 17:59:15.298: D/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x00aa
01-19 17:59:15.318: I/dalvikvm(8182): Could not find method     android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-19 17:59:15.318: W/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     364: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-19 17:59:15.318: D/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-19 17:59:15.318: I/dalvikvm(8182): Could not find method     android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method     android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-19 17:59:15.318: W/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     386: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-19 17:59:15.318: D/dalvikvm(8182): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-19 17:59:15.328: D/AndroidRuntime(8182): Shutting down VM
01-19 17:59:15.328: W/dalvikvm(8182): threadid=1: thread exiting with     uncaught exception (group=0x41bfada0)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182): Process:     com.example.logisticsss, PID: 8182
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182): java.lang.RuntimeException:     Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.logisticsss/com.example.logisticsss.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class     android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at         android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182): Caused by:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class     android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarAct    ivityDelegateBase.java:273)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarAct    ivityDelegateBase.java:225)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:1    02)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     com.example.logisticsss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     ... 11 more
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182): Caused by:     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     ... 24 more
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182): Caused by:     java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:     android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Toolbar_buttonGravity
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:203)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:190)
01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     ... 27 more
```

The app crashes as soon as it starts, If I change the class extension in the MainActivity.java to extend from Activity the app runs just fine, but without the actionbar that I'm trying to get working.

Comment: *Error inflating class     android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar*

Comment: `01-19 17:59:15.338: E/AndroidRuntime(8182):     at     com.example.logisticsss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)` although `NoSuchFieldError`is an indicator that you're probably using wrong version of `android support v7 library`, please post your Gradle build file and dependencies

Comment: What version of Android Support Library do you have and did you do an upgrade the SDK recently? If so, when? Was it working before the upgrade as well?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi never updated and have the API 21

Comment: @EpicPandaForce where do I find the gradle build?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some problems with android support library v7 appcompat, and maybe you need to reinstall or reconfigure your SDK. You may need to reinstall your support SDK libraries, maybe need to reset your project dependencies, add to your compile path, or a combination of one of the options.

After I moved to Lollipop, a bunch of the appcompats for deprecated API levels had debug errors. If you can revert to prior to making an update, you may be able to fix this via going to pre upgrade/update state.

Comment: it may be a conflict then.  check your build directories for precompiled jar libraries, etc.